# Взять из List элементы до определенного элемента

Tags: android, kotlin

Необходимо брать из списка только те элементы, которые находятся до определенного элемента.

Есть такой код(рабочий):
Этот код выполняется когда внутри есть хотя бы один элемент.

```
val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7)
val index = list.indexOf(5)
val newList = list.subList(0, index)
//return 1,2,3,4

val list2 = mutableListOf(5)
val index2 = list2.indexOf(5)
val newList2 = list2.subList(0, index2)
//return empty list
```

Есть ли какое то изящное решение в котлин?

Off top: Не совсем понял как работает dropWhile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dropWhile не совсем то, что нужно, а нужно `takeWhile`:

`val newList = list.takeWhile { it != 5 }`

Comment: Пушка! Огонь!) Спасибо

Comment: @SKULL если вам понравился этот ответ, отметьте его как решение. Для этого нажмите на галочку слева от него